# Write a nested for loop that outputs a series of 1s and 0s in a 10 X 10 grid

Tags: java, modulus

Write a nested for loop that outputs a series of 1s and 0s in a 10 X 10 grid. It should look like this:  **(hint: you might want to use modulus division to print a 1 when it is an even number and zero when odd or vice-versa)**

```
1010101010

1010101010

1010101010

1010101010

1010101010

1010101010

1010101010


1010101010

1010101010

1010101010
```

Here is the prompt for a problem I have to do, my question is how would I go about doing this by using the hint?

Obviously the easy way to do this would be this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i <10; i ++){
        System.out.println("1010101010");
    }        
}
```

But that just seems too simple... any help regarding how to work through this using modulus division is greatly appreciated.

Comment: its not your school assignment right??

Comment: teacher probably want an answer with nested loop and without "1010101010"

Answer (score 2):

You can use nested `for` loops (one to iterate through rows and the other for columns), and print `j % 2`, which will be `0` or `1`:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
         System.out.print(j % 2); // 0 or 1
    }
    System.out.println(); // print new line
}
```

**Note:**

Here, we are starting the loop counter with `1` since we want the pattern `10101...` and not `01010...`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
            System.out.print(j % 2);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: This looks exactly as my answer. You should add something extra.

Answer (score 0):

for even u need 1 and for odd 0,
You can try something like this

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 2; j <= 11; j++) {
            System.out.print(((j % 2)-1)*(-1));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```